# Bundle not installing sub-dependencies

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundle, bundler, jekyll-extensions

I have just written a gem module called [jekyll-google-photos](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-google-photos) in which I have mentioned `fastimage` to be one of the dependencies. Now in my jekyll website repository, I have added `jekyll-google-photos` in the Gemfile. But when I do `bundle install`, bundle doesn't installs `fastimage`. I had to add `fastimage` to my Gemfile as well to make bundle install it. But since it is already a dependency requirement for `jekyll-google-photos`, why won't it get get installed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But since it is already a dependency requirement for jekyll-google-photos, why won't it get get installed automatically?

Only `runtime_dependencies` are installed automatically.

Comment: Ahh Okay. Will try this and let you know.